# Connect to Email Server through VPN

Tags: email, openvpn, smtp

So I'm trying to connect to an email server with a username and password but the only information I have is the user / pass and:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
8100/tcp open  xprint-server
8443/tcp open  https-alt
```

And of course the server IP. I am currently assuming I should be connecting through port 25 or is that incorrect?

I'm putting these details into an email program called Icedove but I'm unsure whether the mail server is pop3 / imap.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I'm unsure whether the mail server is pop3 / imap.

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
8100/tcp open  xprint-server
8443/tcp open  https-alt
```

The above server does not seem to provide POP3 or IMAP (inbound mail). You should speak to your email provider or network administrator to get the server information for inbound email.

The ports used by email (inbound and outbound) depend on:

- The authentication method used
- What port are configured on the email server(s)
- The default ports for POP3, IMAP, and SMTP are listed below.

Looking at the list of your open ports it would appear that the server has:

- SMTP on port 25 (not encrypted, but requires authorisation with user/pass).
- SMTP is used for outbound mail.
- The server does not have any of the default ports open for POP3 or IMAP and a different server will be used for inbound mail.

---

#### Default POP3 ports

```
Server:         Authentication:     Port:
Non-Encrypted   AUTH                110
Secure (SSL)    SSL                 995
```

---

#### Default IMAP ports

```
Server:         Authentication:     Port:
Non-Encrypted   AUTH                143
Secure (TLS)    StartTLS            143
Secure (SSL)    SSL                 993
```

---

#### Default SMTP ports

```
Server:         Authentication:     Port:
Non-Encrypted   AUTH                25 (or 587)
Secure (TLS)    StartTLS            587
Secure (SSL)    SSL                 465
```